# Cannot connect to mongodb database with python pymongo ssh

Tags: python, mongodb, ssh, connection, pymongo

Sorry, I'm very much a noob with mongodb. There is a database that I can access by ssh that I want to write a script for, but I can't seem to be able to get that to work. I ssh with:

> ssh user@##.##...
>   mongo

And I try to connect with my python script by:

```
conn = MongoClient("user@##.##...")
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this using port forwarding:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding